# Turn on Virtualisation settings on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtualbox, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm an AWS newbie. I'm trying to run the latest Hortonworks Sandbox VM image using Virtualbox on a Windows 2012 hvm AMI. I get an error message saying "VT-x is not available. (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)"

What can I do to fix this?

Here's what I've tried:
1. I used the Intel PIU tool which identified that the Virtualisation bit is switched off.
2. I have gone to the Server Manager and confirmed that Hyper-V is off.

Is it possible to access the BIOS and change this setting?

Comment: Pretty much your only option to actually get this working is disabling the virtualization with `VBoxManage modifyvm "<VM_NAME>" --vtxvpid off` and `VBoxManage modifyvm "<VM_NAME> --vtxvpid off`

Answer (score 4):

Your Amazon EC2 instance is itself a virtual machine, and there is no "BIOS" in the way you mean. And Amazon doesn't support any form of accelerated nested virtualization.

This means, among other things, that you cannot use VirtualBox inside an EC2 instance to run 64-bit guests. (You could in theory run 32-bit guests unaccelerated, but it would be painfully slow and expensive.)

You haven't explained what you're trying to accomplish, but whatever it is, using VirtualBox inside an Amazon instance isn't going to be the way to achieve it.

Comment: I've updated my question. I'm trying to run Hortonworks sandbox

Comment: In that case, you're just wasting time and money trying to install the "Sandbox" on a virtual machine in an EC2 virtual machine. If you intend to run Hortonworks on EC2, then just install it normally. The Sandbox is meant for your local workstation.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Hortonworks Sandbox installation [requirements](http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/#install), this runs inside a virtual machine - you can choose the virtual machine to run it on from VMWare, Hyper-V and VirtualBox. Which means the answer from Michael Hampton is correct - this isn't going to work on your Amazon instance. The good news is that from the looks of it you can run this from most current Mac and Windows desktops with at least 4GB of RAM.

Good Luck!